# Launch center pro, skype and the clipboard

Tags: center, skype, launch, urldecode, x-callback-url

I am trying to create an action in Launch Center Pro. It should launch Skype, and call the number in the clipboard. The built in wizard gives this:

```
skype:[clipboard]?call
```

That opens Skype, which then asks me if I want to call a URL encoded version of the number I copied: "%2b1%20%2555%29%20555-5555" (instead of "+1 (555) 555 5555")

How do I urlDECODE this?

I have tried:

```
launch://x-callback-url/clipboard/convert?format={{urldecode}}&x-success={{Skype:}}
(this is using the built in wizard for they system clipboard actions. It opens Skype and does nothing)

skype:[clipboard/convert?format=urldecode]

skype://x-callback-url/clipboard/convert?format=urldecode

launchpro://x-callback-url/clipboard/convert?format=urldecode&x-success={{skype:[clipboard]?call}}
```

But none work. What is the correct formatting for this request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else researching this, I solved it by using another app, TextTool, to strip out non-numerical characters before then passing that to Skype. The final result that worked and still works was:

```
texttool://x-callback-url/transform?text=[clipboard]&method=regex&search=%5CD&replace=&x-success={{skype:+[[output]]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that's Skype failing to decode the incoming URL, not an issue with Launch Center Pro. When passing a URL to Skype apps have to encode that URL (you can't have spaces, parentheses, etc in a valid URL), and Skype should attempt to decode that URL before placing a phone call. Best bet would be to report this to Skype

Comment: Thank you, that's also what LCP's support says. My workaround is to use TextTool to strip out non-numerical characters before passing to Skype.